Determine whether the set $\{A\in M_{2\times3}(\mathbb R) \mid \operatorname{rank}(A)<2\}$ is connected.
This exercise question from my Intro to Real Analysis class asks me to prove/disprove that the set of rank-deficient, real $2\times 3$ matrices is connected. I've managed to prove the set is closed, but not compact. I have no idea where to go from here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you haven't done so already, let me suggest you look at our guidelines for how to ask a good question, with emphasis on providing context and on avoiding "I have no idea" questions. As currently worded, your post is a bare problem statement with no context at all, which can easily attract down votes and close votes on this site.

Hint: It's path-connected, find a path via the origin.

What is the effect of scalar multiplication on such matrices?

@SeverinSchraven That is too much of a hint. It is a solution.

@TedShifrin It is in combination with your comment. By itself, I don't think so (given the level of the question it seems non-trivial for OP to come up with an actual path satisfying the constraint).

@SeverinSchraven Oh my gosh, thank you so much! I tried to show path-connectedness and somehow it never even occurred to me to try passing through the origin. Thank you!!

@LeeMosher Apologies! Still new to the site - I'll keep it in mind for future questions :)

@testaccount I suggest you write up a detailed answer. This way you can ensure that you understand what is going on and it might prove useful for other people.

@SeverinSchraven Done! :) Thanks for the suggestion

@testaccount: Your answer is nicely written.

Let $A$ be the set of rank-deficient, real $2\times3$ matrices. To show $A$ is connected, we show it is path connected — i.e. that we can construct a continuous path between any $P,Q\in A$ such that the path lies entirely within $A$.
Define $\gamma:[0,1]\to M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ by
$$\gamma(t)=\begin{cases}
(1-2t)P&0\leq t<0.5\\
(2t-1)Q&0.5\leq t\leq 1
\end{cases}$$
Clearly each sub-function is continuous, and $(1-2t)P=(2t-1)Q=0$ at $t=0.5$, hence $\gamma$ is continuous on its domain.
Recall that, for any matrix $X$ and any nonzero scalar $c$, $\operatorname{rank}(cX)=\operatorname{rank}(X)$. Therefore, we have
$$\operatorname{rank}(\gamma(t))=\begin{cases}
\operatorname{rank}(P)&t\in[0,0.5)\\
0&t=0.5\\
\operatorname{rank}(Q)&t\in(0.5,1]
\end{cases}$$
which implies that, for any $t\in[0,1]$, $\operatorname{rank}(\gamma(t))<2$ and thus $\gamma(t)\in A$.
$\therefore$ $A$ is connected since it is path connected. $\square$
I'm very new to topology, so any feedback on this proof is appreciated :)
